# Lookback API: Is there a way to include more than one artifact type in a single query?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

In traditional Rally Webservices REST, if I wanted to get all Defects and Stories modified since a certain date, I would need to issue two separate REST GET requests against each of these endpoints:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/hierarchicalrequirement

and

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/defect/

Is there a way to leverage the Lookback API to combine these into one REST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just add `_Type:{$in:["Defect","HierarchicalRequirement"]}` to the query. All of the work item types are stored in the same collection. You can also get back descendent Tasks and TestCases.

Comment: Very handy - it's not uncommon to need a collection of artifacts within a certain time window - and this adds to the ease of obtaining them.